# Write a file using AWK on linux

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, system-administration

I have a file that has several lines of which one line is

```
-xxxxxxxx()xxxxxxxx
```

I want to add the contents of this line to a new file

I did this :

```
awk ' /^-/ {system("echo" $0 ">" "newline.txt")} '
```

but this does not work , it returns an error that says :

```
Unnexpected token '('
```

I believe this is due to the () present in the line. How to overcome this issue?

Comment: Not clear, please be more clear in your post's question. Add samples of Input and sample of output in your post in CODE TAGS `{}` button and let us know then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add proper spaces!

With your erronous `awk ' /^-/ {system("echo" $0 ">" "newline.txt")} '`, the shell command is essentially `echo-xxxxxxxx()xxxxxxxx>newline.txt`, which surely doesn't work. You need to construct a proper shell command inside the `awk` string, and obey `awk`s string concatenation rules, i.e. your intended script should look like this (which is still broken, because `$0` is not properly quoted in the resulting shell command):

`awk '/^-/ { system("echo " $0 " > newline.txt") }'`

However, if you really just need to `echo $0` into a file, you can simply do:

`awk '/^-/ { print $0 > "newline.txt" }'`

Or even more simply

`awk '/^-/' > newline.txt`

Which essentially applies the *default operation* to all records matching `/^-/`, whereby the *default operation* is to `print`, which is short for neatly printing the current record, i.e. this script simply filters out the desired records. The `> newline.txt` redirection outside `awk` simply puts it into a file.

Comment: Thanks. My actual aim was to write output to a file in a different directory. The directory name is represented by a variable in awk.
So i used your help and did this :

awk ' / ^ - / { print $0 > dirNameVariable"/newline.txt" } ' 

however i got an error that said :

awk : cannot open "design/newline.txt" for output  (No such file or directory)

Any idea why? (design is the value that the variable dirNameVariable holds in awk)

Comment: You have to make sure that the directory actually exists – either relative to the current directory from which you invoke `awk`, or as an absolute path expression. And write permissions are required as well, of course.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `system`, `echo` commands, simply:

```
awk '/^-/ {print $1}' file > newfile
```

This will capture lines starting with `-` and truncate the rest if there's a space.

```
awk '/^-/ {print $0}' file > newfile
```

Would capture the entire line including spaces.

You could use **grep** also:

```
grep -o '^-.*' file > newfile
```

Captures any lines starting with `-`

```
grep -o '^-.*().*' file > newfile
```

Would be more specific and capture lines starting with `-` also containing `()`

Comment: I would recommend using `print $0` to print the whole line instead of `print $1` because you never know if there is a space in the `xxxx()xxxx`, also `awk` might be an overkill for this task a `grep` command would be more than enough ;-)

Comment: @Allan: The OP should indicate that the string has a space in it (edit  question). And yes I was going to suggest grep also, but it's really up to them.

Comment: it is not my question lol hahaha you never know what OP **really** wants ;-)

Comment: nice recap answer +1! :) :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all for simple extraction of patterns from file, you do not need to use `awk` it is an overkill, `grep` would be more than enough for the task:

**INPUT:**

```
$ more file
123
-xxxxxxxx()xxxxxxxx
abc
-xyxyxxux()xxuxxuxx
123
abc
123
```

**command:**

```
$ grep -oE '^-[^(]+\(\).*' file                                                                                                  
-xxxxxxxx()xxxxxxxx
-xyxyxxux()xxuxxuxx
```

**explanations:**

Option: `-oE` to define the output as the pattern and not the whole line (can be removed)
Regex: `^-[^(]+\(\).*` will select lines that starts with `-` and contains `()`

You can redirect your output to a `new_file` by adding `> new_file` at the end of your command.

Comment: Youre welcome. You do need to add the `-E` for `+` though, or maybe escaping the `+` would be enough in your grep, idk. The point is that `+` in a BRE is just a literal character and grep uses BREs by default so while you don't need `-P` you do need something...